# Providing additional Config files using VS Code

Tags: ballerina

How can we use multiple .toml files as specified in https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-spec/blob/master/configurable/spec.md#locating-toml-files using Visual Studio Code?  (Assuming that I want to use `Config.toml` and `B.toml`)
In `.vscode/launch.json` I added:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Ballerina Run",
            "type": "ballerina",
            "request": "launch",
            "programArgs": [],
            "commandOptions": [],
            "env": {
                "BAL_CONFIG_FILES": "./Config.toml:./B.toml"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am not able to provide configurable variables through `B.toml`, only the variables added via the `Config.toml` are being picked up.
It is working when providing config files through command line as follows:
In Linux `BAL_CONFIG_FILES="./Config.toml:./B.toml" bal run`.
But it does not work by adding the config files to `.vscode/launch.json` and run the program by pressing the `Run` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS Code, internally the `Run` button will only open a new terminal and run the `bal run` command. The config you added in the `.vscode/launch.json` are not used there.